# android layout: making a textview to take up a percent of the creen

Tags: android, xml, format

In my xml I am trying to get a checkbox to be at the bottom of the screen and the scrollview to take up the rest of the view. I have tried fill_parent for the scrollview but that just pushes the checkbox out of sight.  I was thinking if there way a way to specify a percent of the screen instead of a hard coded amount that would help when using the app on multiple devices.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/messagesCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"

        android:text="@string/messagesCheckBox"
        android:textColor="@color/checkBoxTextColor"
        android:background="#ffffffff" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollerId"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="375sp"

        android:scrollbars="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/messageText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"

            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text=""
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:paddingBottom="10sp" />
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a `RelativeLayout` you can use `layout_above`

```
<RelativeLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView android:layout_above="@+id/messagesCheckBox"
    android:id="@+id/scrollerId"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
    .
    .
    </ScrollView>
    <CheckBox
    android:id="@id/messagesCheckBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
    android:text="@string/messagesCheckBox"
    android:textColor="@color/checkBoxTextColor"
    android:background="#ffffffff" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

In this case the first child will always appear above the second.

Answer (score 0):

there is a tag android:layout_above in android
add this to scroll view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/messagesCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"

        android:text="@string/messagesCheckBox"
        android:textColor="@color/checkBoxTextColor"
        android:background="#ffffffff" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollerId"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_Parent"
        android:layout_above = "@+id/messagesCheckBox"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/messageText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"

            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text=""
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:paddingBottom="10sp" />
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```